# What do all the numbers in `top` mean?

Tags: linux, top

I've been using `top` command for a while, and I know what some numbers mean, but most of them are still a mystery. I would like to have an explanation about what each value means. I googled for this, and found [this](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm), but I quickly realized that the fields described there are different from the fields I see when I run `top` in Debian.

Is there anywhere an accurate legend of the `top` screen?

Comment: if you like top, try htop!

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided is essentially the man page for top.  Try reading through `man top` to get the specifics for your system.  Specifically, section 2, which explains all the fields.


--Christopher Karel

Comment: Checked `map top`. Still cryptic. At the very best it mixes up the order of fields and puts them under different names. Also, I didn't see an explanation of the lines at top. I wish there was just a simple graphical legend to this screen.